# Using a robot arm to reach a specific point with arbitrary orientation

Tags: optimization, robotics

I want to use a 6-DoF robot arm to reach a user-given point

> $$P_{target} = (x, y, z)$$

with arbitrary orientation.

My robot arm is equipped with a laser pen and what I want to do is to aim at point $P_{target}$ along the axis perpendicular to the flange face of my robot arm with a predefined distance $D$.

I want to minimize the movement of my robot arm, that is, with given start pose

> $$(x_i, y_i, z_i, q_{xi}, q_{yi}, q_{zi}, q_{wi})$$

and final pose

> $$(x_f, y_f, z_f, q_{xf}, q_{yf}, q_{zf}, q_{wf})$$

the value

> $${(x_f-x_i)}^2 + {(y_f - y_i)}^2 + {(z_f - z_i)}^2 + {(q_{xf} - q_{xi})}^2 + {(q_{yf} - q_{yi})}^2 + {(q_{zf} - q_{zi})}^2 + {(q_{wf} - q_{wi})}^2$$

can be optimized.

How could I list the equations and get the result

> $$(q_{xf}, q_{yf}, q_{zf}, q_{wf})$$

?

Thanks a lot for any hint and help.

Comment: I suspect that what makes the problem difficult is not yet articulated in your Question.  On one side you wrote about minimizing "the movement of my robot arm" and give a sum of squares "value" to be "optimized".  But it is unclear what choices you have in arguments.  The values of the initial and final poses seem to be fixed.  Probably you have in mind some steps between these poses.  Also there are likely some constraints and interactions between variables that would inform the desired "solution".

Comment: To make typing equations and formulas less laborious: you only need a dollar sign at the start and end of the whole formula, not round each term. (Or a double dollar sign at each end if you want the formula to appear in "display format" on a line of its own.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

A possible variational formulation assuming for simplicity final position without final orientation.

Supposing you have the end point dynamics as

$$
\ddot X = \Phi(X, \dot X, \theta)
$$

where $\theta$ are the elbow actuators, you need to obtain

$$
\min_{\theta}\int_0^{t_f} ||\dot X|| dt\ \ \mbox{s. t.}\ \ \ \ddot X = \Phi(X, \dot X,\theta), \, X(t_f) = X_f
$$

NOTE

We assumed minimum movement as minimum path covered distance.